# Is the Azure CloudTable column limit per entity, or for the entire table?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

The Table service documentation states that an entity can have up to 252 custom properties (ie. columns). Does this limit apply per entity, or is this enforced for all unique columns in the table?

Impractical example to demonstrate the point: Can entity A have A1 to A252 and entity B, B1 to B252 as a column?

Relevant quote from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model):

> An entity can have up to 255 properties, including 3 system properties described in the following section. Therefore, the user may include **up to 252 custom properties**, in addition to the 3 system properties. The combined size of all data in an entity's properties cannot exceed 1 MiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table item (e.g. *entity*) can have a total of 255 properties, as the docs call out. This is per entity. There is no defined schema (it's up to you what to store in each entity). The properties (outside of the common 3 properties) for each entity have no dependence on, or relationship to, other entities. Feel free to store a different set of 252 properties per entity.

The per-entity size limit is independent of number of properties in an entity.

Comment: thanks, does that mean that the column names are stored per entity or does the table somehow keep an index of what column id's entities use and prevent storing duplicate id's?

Comment: No master index. The only indexed properties are your partition key + row key. This is why it takes a while to search through the other properties, if you have a lot of data and try doing a partition scan or table scan.

Comment: I guess the term index was misleading. I didn't mean that the values are indexed but that the keys/columns are somehow indexed. eg. if my column name is 255 bytes, does every entity that uses this column take 255 bytes each for the 'key' or does the table keep a reference of unique columns?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. No such reference of unique columns or column references across a table (aside from rowkey/partitionkey/timestamp). Entities are independent things. You can use property `a1` in one entity and `a1` in another, and store completely different content. Schema management is up to you.